# Unable to create table entry in php mysql db using below code in hibernate(using Ampps)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Issue  -   I am using mac OS Mojave, I have created one program which will create a table in the db named HibernateTutorials, I have installed Ampps and started it on 3306 port to create db. Now whenever i try to create table I am getting below error.

Error -

```
Mar 15, 2019 1:10:34 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.gontuseries.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQDialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:129)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQDialect
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:133)
    ... 25 more
```

Please find the below classes I have created -

Main class -

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.fasterxml.classmate.AnnotationConfiguration;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student_Info stu = new Student_Info();
        stu.setName("Aniket");
        stu.setRoll_no(1);

        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Student_Info.class);

        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(stu);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sf.close();


    }
}
```

Student_Info -

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT_INFORMATION")
public class Student_Info {

    @Id
    private int roll_no;

    public int getRoll_no() {
        return roll_no;
    }

    public void setRoll_no(int roll_no) {
        this.roll_no = roll_no;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HibernateTutorials</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool(use the built in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- sql dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_clas">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed sql to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->
        <mapping class="com.gontuseries.hibernate.Student_Info" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Note - please suggest if the problem is in configuration or in code as the code I think is good;

Answer (score 0):

You have typing error in dialect configuration

> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQDialect